# Name, Email and other profile information from Google's OAuth API

Tags: oauth, google-api, userinfo

I want both name , email and other profile information for a user once he/she logs in using google oauth.

incidentally , if I use

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

as the scope , it will give me the user email id 
and if I use

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile , it will give me other info like url and image etc.

But how can I get both the email and other relevant information using one such API scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just join them with "+" separator, as `scope' parameter.

see http://code.google.com/intl/ja/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#formingtheurl